# prove a projection map is closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ consisting of the two axes. I want to prove the continuous map $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y) = x$ is a closed map.

Comment: Have you tried showing that f is a homemorphism?

Comment: I don't think f is a homeomorphism

Comment: What is "the two axis"???

Comment: union of the x axis and the y axis

Comment: "I don't know where to start." Start with the definitions. What is a closed map? what is a continuous function?

Comment: Effectively, this problem is just saying limits don't change if we change the value of a function at a single point.  To prove it, let $C \subseteq X$ be closed and let $x_n \in f(C)$ be a sequence converging to $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  Show $x \in f(C)$ by considering $x=0$ and $x\neq 0$ as separate cases.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be a close subset of $X$. To show that $f(C)$ is closed take a convergent sequence in this set, say $f(a_n,b_n) \to t$ with $(a_n,b_n) \in C$ for all $n$. Now $(a_n,b_n) \in X$  implies that either $a_n=0$ or $b_n=0$ for  each $n$. This implies that either$a_n=0$ for infinitely many values of $n$ or $b_n=0$ for infinitely many values of $n$ . In the first case $t=0$ and $0 \in f(C)$ because $0=f(a_k,b_k)$ for  any $k$ with $a_k=0$. [There is at least one such $k$, in fact infinitely many such $k$]. In the second case $f(a_n,b_n) \to t$ implies that $a_n \to t$ and $b_n=0$ along a subsequence Thus $(a_n,b_n) \to (t,0)$ along a subsequence. Since $C$ is closed it follows that $(t,0) \in C$ from which it follows that $t \in f(C)$. This proves that $f(C)$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this argument not involving convergent sequences. 
Let $A$ be closed in $X$ and pick a point $x_0 \notin f(A)$ and if we can find some neighborhood of $x_0$ not intersect $f(A)$ then we are done since then $f(A)$ will be its own closure and hence closed. We proceed with two cases: if $x_0 \neq 0$, then $f^{-1}(\{x_0\}) = \{(x_0, 0)\}$, since $A$ is closed we can find a tiny neighborhood $U$ of $(x_0, 0)$ not intersecting $A$. Then $f(U)$ will be a neighborhood of $x_0$ disjoint from $f(A)$. In the case $x_0 = 0$, we pick the point $(0, 0) \in f^{-1}(\{x_0\})$ and again find a small neighborhood $V$ of $(0,0)$ disjoint from $A$, then $f(V)$ is disjoint from $f(A)$ and we are done.